# Rails 2.3.8: how to parse JSON with field names other than DB columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, syntax

I'm sure there's an easy solution for this but I'm new to Rails and need help with syntax.

In my controller I have:

```
@products = Product.all
format.json { render :json => @products }
```

And it works fine, returning data with the default column names used in the DB:

```
"product": {
  "created_at": "2010-10-08T17:24:27Z",
  "id": 24,
  "product_date": "2010-08-08",
  "product_name": "Product One",
  "updated_at": "2010-10-08T17:36:00Z"
}
```

What I need is something like:

```
"product": {
  "created_at": "2010-10-08T17:24:27Z",
  "id": 24,
  "start": "2010-08-08",
  "title": "Product One",
  "updated_at": "2010-10-08T17:36:00Z"
}
```

That is, changing **product_date** to **start** and **product_name** to **title**, but only in the JSON output.

It seems like an easy problem to solve but I'm not sure how to express it in Ruby/Rails syntax, so I would really appreciate any help.  I cannot rename the database columns.

Comment: Do you need to override it only for one specific action, or every time a Product is serialized to json?

Comment: Every time.  I want to use a jQuery plugin that requires specific field names for the JSON data passed to it.  I would like to be able to use the same action to render XML (with default field names), and JSON with modified field names.  Would I maybe create a new variable for the JSON data, or do something within the render statement?

Comment: If anyone else is able to offer any insight that would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the JSON output for all Products, everywhere and all the time, simply override the `to_json` method on your Product model.

Here's the simple way to do that (in your Product class definition):

```
def to_json
  ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({
    :created_at => created_at
    :id => id
    :start => product_date
    :title => product_name
    :updated_at => updated_at
  })
end
```

You could get fancier and plug in a custom Serializer, but this should suffice for your purposes. One drawback of doing this so explicitly is that if your schema changes, this will have to be updated. This will also break the options usually available to the `to_json` method (`:include`, `:only`, etc) so, maybe it's not too hot.

Comment: I knew it'd be easy, just didn't know how to go about it. Thanks Jason.  Just out of curiosity, how would you go about it if you don't want to alter the JSON output application-wide?  I'm mainly interested in the syntax difference between the two situations.

Comment: Hmm, a simple way would be to just build a new hash to pass to `render`.

Comment: I'm getting a "wrong number of arguments" error trying to access the JSON data with the above method in my model.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you can show me how to do it the hash way you suggested?